# Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates

Tags: botframework, ngrok

I am developing a Bot application with the Azure Bot Framework and registered the bot on Azure and enabled direct line channel.

I have tested my application in Visual Studios (IIS Express) with Conveyor by keyoti and it works fine.

Now I need to try to run in a docker container, so I can't use conveyor so I tried a ngrok tunnel service, but when I try to run the application, I am getting an error

`System.Net.Http.CurlException: Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates`

The exception is raised on turnContext.SendActivityAsync.

NB: When I load fiddler on my machine, everything works fine, so I am not sure what the issue is.

Please let me know if there is any setting I need to do to get this working.

Any advice or help will be appreciated.?

Comment: Have you tried using the emulator? Using a combo of ngrok/emulator, I was able to test my bots in a docker container.

Comment: I'd be happy to help you with Conveyor, there is a way to use it standalone.  Just need to understand what you're doing a bit better.  You're welcome to use the support email or form on the conveyor.cloud website to contact me directly.  If I can get it to work for you I will post a proper answer here.